# My own model in matter.js

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm using Matter.js to program a simple game. I'm having trouble figuring out how best to hook my model into Matter.js.

My game features bacteria, and I'd like to have a class `Bacterium` so that I can manage these guys. In my current implementation, this class creates and stores its own `Matter.Body`, which I pass to the engine. This is where I'm running into trouble. I'd like to update certain aspects of my model when bacteria collide with each other, and with walls, but I can't find an efficient way to locate which bacteria in my model are colliding in my Matter collision handler.

Should I extend `Matter.Body`'s prototype to do this? Any advice, or larger matter projects on the web that I should look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `Render.collisions` function in the `Render.js` class. This function renders all the collisions that occur in the frame that is being rendered. I think by understanding how they render it there you can work out what you need in you situation.

Remember that matterjs uses a game loop which is really different from the event based setup that webpages normally work with. Take a look at the `Render.js` class to better understand how to work with working with the engine that matterjs provides.

Answer (score 0):

Don't extend prototypes you don't own. Adding the MJS body as a field in your class is a fine approach, and you can keep track of which bodies are colliding by using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to associate each MJS body with its corresponding instance of your class.

Here's an example that hooks into `collisionStart` and `collisionEnd` MJS events to call methods on a custom class that composes on MJS bodies.

```js
class Box {
  constructor(x, y, w, h, bodyOpts) {
    // composition, not inheritance
    this.body = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
      x, y, w, h, {
        ...bodyOpts,
        render: {fillStyle: "green"}
      },
    );

    // ... other properties relevant to your app ...
  }

  highlight() {
    this.body.render.fillStyle = "red";
  }
  unhighlight() {
    this.body.render.fillStyle = "green";
  }
}

const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
engine.gravity.y = 0; // enable top-down
const map = {width: 300, height: 300};
const render = Matter.Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine,
  options: {...map, wireframes: false},
});
const rnd = n => ~~(Math.random() * n);
const boxes = [...Array(40)].map(() => new Box(
  rnd(map.width),  // x
  rnd(map.height), // y
  rnd(10) + 15,    // w
  rnd(10) + 15,    // h
  {angle: rnd(Math.PI * 2)}
));
const walls = new Set([
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    0, map.height / 2, 20, map.height, {isStatic: true}
  ),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    map.width / 2, 0, map.width, 20, {isStatic: true}
  ),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    map.width, map.height / 2, 20, map.height, {isStatic: true}
  ),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    map.width / 2, map.height, map.width, 20, {isStatic: true}
  ),
]);
const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(
  engine, {element: document.body}
);
Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, [
  ...boxes.map(e => e.body), ...walls, mouseConstraint
]);
const bodiesToBoxes = new Map(boxes.map(e => [e.body, e]));

Matter.Events.on(engine, "collisionStart", event => {
  for (const {bodyA, bodyB} of event.pairs) {
    if (bodiesToBoxes.has(bodyA)) {
      bodiesToBoxes.get(bodyA).highlight();
    }

    if (bodiesToBoxes.has(bodyB)) {
      bodiesToBoxes.get(bodyB).highlight();
    }
  }
});
Matter.Events.on(engine, "collisionEnd", event => {
  for (const {bodyA, bodyB} of event.pairs) {
    if (bodiesToBoxes.has(bodyA)) {
      bodiesToBoxes.get(bodyA).unhighlight();
    }

    if (bodiesToBoxes.has(bodyB)) {
      bodiesToBoxes.get(bodyB).unhighlight();
    }
  }
});
Matter.Render.run(render);
Matter.Runner.run(Matter.Runner.create(), engine);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

The [`Body.label`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_label) property can help in distinguishing the body types, but ultimately MJS doesn't offer any sort of entity management solution beyond that. I caution against over-reliance on `.label`. Ultimately, it's up to you to choose a design that suits the needs of your app.