# Detect if Matter.js Body is Circle

Tags: javascript, game-physics, physics, matter.js

I want to test if a particular Matter body is a circle or not, as in:

```
const compounds = Matter.Composite.allBodies(engine.world)
compounds.forEach(compound => compound.parts.forEach(part => {
  const isCircle = ???
  if (isCircle) console.log(part.id, 'is a circle')
  else console.log(part.id, 'is not a circle')
})
```

I can't find an official way to test if a Matter body was created as a circle. How can I test if a body was created with `new Matter.Body.Circle` versus another Body constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You can `console.log(a_circle)` and check for something to identify a circle by.
I think you can check for `a_circle.circleRadius` or `a_circle.label=='Circle Body'`

EDIT: I have looked at the source code before posting this. It's a safe bet (for now as there is no documentation) because you can see that otherwise is just a polygon.

```
Matter.Bodies.circle = function(x, y, radius, options, maxSides) {
  options = options || {};

  var circle = {
    label: 'Circle Body',
    circleRadius: radius
  };

  // approximate circles with polygons until true circles implemented in SAT
  maxSides = maxSides || 25;
  var sides = Math.ceil(Math.max(10, Math.min(maxSides, radius)));

  // optimisation: always use even number of sides (half the number of unique axes)
  if (sides % 2 === 1)
    sides += 1;

  return Bodies.polygon(x, y, sides, radius, Common.extend({}, circle, options));
}
```

Comment: I'm considered about the long term reliability of this strategy. I can't find any official documentation or discussion promoting this approach, so I'm concerned it's not recommended.

Comment: I see no benefit to using a circle-specific property instead of a label. They both achieve the exact same thing but one tool is intended for the purpose and the other is a hack/workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73178510/6243352) suggests looking for circle-specific properties. One problem is, these can change in future Matter.js releases. Also, it doesn't make for readable, intuitive code, and can lead to surprising bugs when additional body types wind up containing a property unexpectedly.

Better is to use the internal `label` property (also suggested in that answer), which should be stable and defaults to the seemingly-useful `"Rectangle Body"` and `"Circle Body"`. For simple use cases, this works. Since it's possible to set the label to an object to store arbitrary custom data on the body, it's tempting to go further and use labels for just about everything.

However, I generally ignore labels. The reason is that it pushes too much of the client logic into a physics library that's not really designed for entity management. Furthermore, either of these approaches (labels or body-specific properties) involves iterating all of the bodies to filter out the type you're interested in.

Although no context was provided about the app, having to call `allBodies` often seems like a potential antipattern. It might be time to consider a redesign so you don't have to. What if you have 5 circles and 500 other bodies? Recursively iterating all 500 on every frame just to find the 5 is a huge waste of resources to achieve something that should be easy and efficient.

My preferred solution for entity management is to simply keep track of each type upon creation, putting them into data structures that are tuned to application-specific needs.

For example, the following script shows a method of efficiently determining body type by presenting the body as a key to a pre-built `types` map.

```js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
engine.gravity.y = 0; // enable top-down
const map = {width: 300, height: 300};
const render = Matter.Render.create({
  element: document.querySelector("#container"),
  engine,
  options: {...map, wireframes: false},
});
const rnd = n => ~~(Math.random() * n);

const rects = [...Array(20)].map(() => Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
  rnd(map.width),  // x
  rnd(map.height), // y
  rnd(10) + 15,    // w
  rnd(10) + 15,    // h
  {
    angle: rnd(Math.PI * 2),
    render: {fillStyle: "pink"}
  }
));
const circles = [...Array(20)].map(() => Matter.Bodies.circle(
  rnd(map.width),  // x
  rnd(map.height), // y
  rnd(5) + 10,     // r
  {render: {fillStyle: "red"}}
));
const walls = [
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    0, map.height / 2, 20, map.height, {
      isStatic: true, render: {fillStyle: "yellow"}
    }
  ),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    map.width / 2, 0, map.width, 20, {
      isStatic: true, render: {fillStyle: "yellow"}
    }
  ),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    map.width, map.height / 2, 20, map.height, {
      isStatic: true, render: {fillStyle: "yellow"}
    }
  ),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    map.width / 2, map.height, map.width, 20, {
      isStatic: true, render: {fillStyle: "yellow"}
    }
  ),
];
const rectangle = Symbol("rectangle");
const circle = Symbol("circle");
const wall = Symbol("wall");
const types = new Map([
  ...rects.map(e => [e, rectangle]),
  ...circles.map(e => [e, circle]),
  ...walls.map(e => [e, wall]),
]);
const bodies = [...types.keys()];
const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(
  engine, {element: document.querySelector("#container")}
);
Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, [
  ...bodies, mouseConstraint
]);

const runner = Matter.Runner.create();
Matter.Events.on(runner, "tick", event => {
  const underMouse = Matter.Query.point(
    bodies,
    mouseConstraint.mouse.position
  );
  
  if (underMouse.length) {
    const descriptions = underMouse.map(e =>
      types.get(e).description
    );
    document.querySelector("#type-hover").textContent = `
      ${descriptions.join(", ")} hovered
    `;
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector("#type-hover").textContent = `
      [hover a body]
    `;
  }

  if (mouseConstraint.body) {
    document.querySelector("#type-click").textContent = `
      ${types.get(mouseConstraint.body).description} selected
    `;
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector("#type-click").textContent = `
      [click and drag a body]
    `;
  }
});

Matter.Render.run(render);
Matter.Runner.run(runner, engine);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>

<h3 id="type-click">[click and drag a body]</h3>
<h3 id="type-hover">[hover a body]</h3>
<div id="container"></div>
```

If creating and destroying bodies can happen dynamically, a function would need to be written to handle data structure bookkeeping.

Another approach that might work well for some apps is to have a few type-specific sets or maps. This allows you to quickly access all entities of a particular type. This becomes particularly useful once you begin composing bodies as properties of custom classes.

There's no reason you can't have both structures--a reverse lookup that gives the type or custom class given a MJS body, and a structure that contains references to all entities or MJS bodies of a particlar type.

The reverse lookup could enable logic like "on click, take an action on a specific MJS body depending on its type" or "on click, locate my custom class/model associated with this MJS body", while collections support logic like "destroy all enemies".

Ideally, code shouldn't be doing much type-checking. With proper OOP design, you can implement classes that respond correctly to methods regardless of their type. For example, if you have `Enemy` and `Ally` classes that each respond to a click, you might create a method called `handleClick` in each class. This allows you to use code like `clickedEntity.handleClick();` without having to know whether `clickedEntity` is an `Enemy` or `Ally`, thereby avoiding the need for a "get type" operation entirely.

---

For more design suggestions for Matter.js projects, see:

- [How do you access a body by its label in MatterJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092182/how-do-you-access-a-body-by-its-label-in-matterjs/72117671#72117671)
- [My own model in matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575883/my-own-model-in-matter-js/72849469#72849469)

Comment: I use TypeScript classes, model specific labels, and a variety of containers to manage interactions when appropriate. Some projects have features that are most efficiently applied to each body in a conditional way, so I need to know how to handle those cases, which I agree are less common. For these operations, applying the behavior to each container individually creates unnecessary and burdensome repetition, or many new behavior specific containers. I'm looking for an alternative for the situations where detecting would be convenient and resource-saving.

Comment: I'm not sure I grasp your scenario clearly. You might want to edit your question describing your use case and explain how the techniques covered here don't apply to your scenario, if that's what you're saying here. I can only speak generally, otherwise. I've described the primary efficient techniques I know of in this post as well as in the linked answers, so I'm not sure what else to offer here without more details. You can add as many containers as necessary to create groupings up front that _do_ represent the operations you want to take so you don't have to filter all bodies.

Comment: Also, if you have a bunch of repeated checks to see which container a body belongs to and adding another container isn't sufficient for some reason, then use the label or the "type lookup" step shown in this post to figure out which container to look in. That's a maximum of 2 hashmap lookups, which should be very efficient (and can potentially be reduced to bitwise ops if you're really pressed for speed and you don't have too many categories). As far as code cleanliness, add a function that abstracts away the dirty work and I don't see how this wouldn't work for the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: By the way, MJS is (just) a headless physics library, not a game engine, entity management solution or rendering framework, so you basically always have to roll your own EM or use a third-party library. There is no "official" solution beyond the label property. The fact that it offers built-in labels and a prototyping renderer creates endless consternation/misuse when people try to use MJS for things it's not really designed for (typically entity management and rendering). Hence the label warning. This is a good thing--MJS would probably be bloated if it offered a tightly-coupled EM solution.